# Understanding JS filter method on an exported variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm having difficulty googling an explanation of `filter` in this scenario that makes sense to me. Can someone ELIF?

I have a `script.js` file with the following:

```
let cart = [];
const products = [
  {
    name: 'Cherry',
    price: 10,
    quantity: 0,
    productId: 1,
    image: '../images/cherry.jpg',
  }, ...
];


function decreaseQuantity(productId) {
  let product = products.find((product) => product.productId === productId);
  product.quantity -= 1;
  if (product.quantity === 0) {
    cart = cart.filter((p) => p.quantity != 0);
    console.log(cart);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  products,
  cart,
  decreaseQuantity,
};
```

In a Jest file `script.test.js`:

```
const cart = require('./script.js');

describe('Cart Functionality Tests', () => {
  let product1 = cart.products[1];
  let cartArr = cart.cart;

  test('decrease quantity from 1 to 0 removes item from cart', () => {
    cart.decreaseQuantity(product1.productId);
    expect(product1.quantity).toEqual(0);
    console.log(cartArr);
    expect(cartArr).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

The `decreaseQuantity` test is failing because `cartArr` isn't being modified properly.

Using `splice` works because it modifies the items directly. But `filter` and reassigning the new array to the original `cart` doesn't modify the array as I expected.

```
cart = cart.filter((p) => p.quantity != 0);
```

Shouldn't `cartArr` in the jest test get modified since it's a shallow copy?

Comment: i mean, in `decreaseQuantity` you're not modifying `cart` array's items in any way. how do you expect it to change upon product's quantity change?

Comment: "*reassigning the new array to the original cart doesn't modify the array*" - that sums up your problem pretty well. Reassignment to the `cart` variable only reassigns that variable, nothing else - not the `module.exports.cart` property nor the `cartArr` in your test! What you want is to *modifiy* the array instead, using e.g. `splice`.